# Problems with button event handling for Vue project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, vue.js

I am new to Vue. I want to create simple button click callback, the callback method will show name of the button what clicked. Callback works but the button name is still "undefined".

HTML code:

```
<button class="w-32" attr-type="submit" @click="sendClick">btnName</button>
```

TS code:

```
sendClick(event:  React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {     
    if (event) {
        const { target } = event
        if (target){ 
            console.log( ((target as HTMLButtonElement).value));
        }
    } 
}
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Sources:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#inline-handlers

https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmlbuttonelement.html#name

https://freshman.tech/snippets/typescript/fix-value-not-exist-eventtarget/

Comment: What name do you expect it to be? btnName is the element contents. If you need to unambiguously identify an element that sendClick was called on, you can pass an id directly

Comment: @EstusFlask I thought that value of the element is "btnName".  I don't need ID, only the name of the element for using in backend.

Comment: From your description, you want to identify it somehow, so "id" makes sense, but you can call it a value if you have to. There's no "value" of a button, it's not input field. btnName is just arbitrary visible text. It could be html element and not a string. If you want to identify it somehow in app logic, you can do it explicitly, like `@click="sendClick('btnName')"

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for reminding me that it is DOM architecture. I tried ".firstChild.textContent" instead of ".value" and most of times it works and sometimes it returns emty string, but it will be probably caused by the fact that I am using now naiveUI buttons.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the problem with textContent. I wouldn't rely on it if semantic values are needed

Comment: @EstusFlask It is interesting that if I replace naive-ui "<n-button" by standard "<button" it works fine. But thank you for that recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was deduced from comments to main post.

```
  if (event) {
    const { target } = event
    if (target) {
      var el: HTMLButtonElement = (target as HTMLButtonElement)
      if (el && el.firstChild) {
        console.log(el.firstChild.textContent);
      }
    }
  }
```